# Cosmos DB Mongo implementation - different return type for "count" than Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, bson

When running a `count` on something, Mongo DB returns an `int` (32 Bit value) in its BSON document representation, whereas Azure Cosmos DB apparently returns a `long` (64 Bit value).

Is this something which is by design, and has to be taken care of in client code? It might break things which expect an `int`, e.g. by using `org.bson.Document.getInteger("count")` instead of the more lengthy `((Number)doc.get("count")).longValue()`, or similar.

Are there other places where the Azure Cosmos DB behaves just *slightly* different from Mongo DB one should be aware of when trying to use Cosmos as a drop-in replacement for Mongo?

Comment: The result of the `count` command is normally returned as a 64-bit long so the difference you are seeing may actually be related to your driver or server version. What specific version of MongoDB driver and server are you testing with when a 32-bit int is returned for a `count`?

Comment: For local testing, we're using the `mongo:3.4.7` docker image, and the Spring Boot client library, which uses `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.4.3`.

Comment: Addendum: In both cases the client (and thus the library) is the same, so it seems likely that there is a difference in the server implementation.